# Play a gif in python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, gif, animated-gif

I have been trying to play a gif in python 3.5.2 , i've made a crude working version, using this code:

```
import turtle
import time

def playgif(frame):
    screen = turtle.Screen()
    screen.setup(700,700)
    screen.bgpic(frame)
    screen.exitonclick

phrame1 = "frame_0_delay-0.08s.gif"
phrame2 = "frame_1_delay-0.08s.gif"
phrame3 = "frame_2_delay-0.08s.gif"
phrame4 = "frame_3_delay-0.08s.gif"
phrame5 = "frame_4_delay-0.08s.gif"
phrame6 = "frame_5_delay-0.08s.gif"
phrame7 = "frame_6_delay-0.08s.gif"
phrame8 = "frame_7_delay-0.08s.gif"
phrame9 = "frame_8_delay-0.08s.gif"
phrame10 = "frame_9_delay-0.08s.gif"
phrame11 = "frame_10_delay-0.08s.gif"
phrame12 = "frame_11_delay-0.08s.gif"

again = 1
while again == 1:
    playgif(phrame1)
    time.sleep(0.08)
    playgif(phrame2)
    time.sleep(0.08)
    playgif(phrame3)
    time.sleep(0.08)
    playgif(phrame4)
    time.sleep(0.08)
    playgif(phrame5)
    time.sleep(0.08)
    playgif(phrame6)
    time.sleep(0.08)
    playgif(phrame7)
    time.sleep(0.08)
    playgif(phrame8)
    time.sleep(0.08)
    playgif(phrame9)
    time.sleep(0.08)
    playgif(phrame10)
    time.sleep(0.08)
    playgif(phrame11)
    time.sleep(0.08)
    playgif(phrame12)
    time.sleep(0.08)
```

since i was not sure how to index inside a gif, i had to break it up into separate gifs, for each frame. I wanted to know if there was a shorter way of doing it.
I was thinking perhaps having something like this would work but i keep getting an error:

```
    again = 1
    iterations = 0
    while again == 1:
        playgif(phrame+iterations)
        time.sleep(0.08)
        iterations += 1
```

my crude method works, but after about 50 frames its not feasible

Comment: Is this a question about playing Gifs or about iteration and string concatenation?

Comment: playing a GIF. I think though when i try to do the frame + iterations, i expect it to address a predefined variable, but instead i think it treats it like a string concatenation.